# HTML onclick /JS function not working

Tags: javascript, html

Im practicing on codepen and for some reason, the AddtoInput function in hte javascript code doesnt seem to run/compile. Not sure if its something with onclick in html, its simple enough so I dont think so..

HTML code

```
  <div id = "container">
    <div id="header">Calculator</div>
    <div id = "calculator">
      <div id="top">
        <div class="clear" onclick='Clear()'> C </div>
        <div class="screen">
          <input id="screen" type="text" placeholder="Let's do some math!"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class = "squares">
          <span onclick = "AddtoInput(1)">1</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(2)">2</span>
          <span type="button" onclick='AddtoInput(3)'>3</span>
          <span class="operator add" onclick='oper(+)'>+</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(4)">4</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(5)">5</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(6)">6</span>
          <span class="operator sub" onclick='oper(-)'>-</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(7)">7</span>
          <span  onclick="AddtoInput(8)">8</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(9)">9</span>
          <span class="operator" onclick='oper(/)'>÷</span>
          <span type="button" onclick="AddtoInput(0)">0</span>
          <span>.</span>
          <span class="equal" onclick='calc()'>=</span>
          <span class="operator" onclick='oper(*)'>x</span>
      <div>
     </div> 

   </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
var StringOper = '';
var InString = 0;
var InString2 = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("screen");

function AddtoInput(num) {
  window.alert("I am In!!");
  InString = InString*10;
  InString = InString + num;
  elem.value = InString;
}

function Clear(){
  window.alert("I am In clear");
  InString = 0;
  elem.value = InString;
}

function oper(operator) {
  for (var i= 0,i<4;i++){
    if(operators[i] == operator)
      StringOper = operator;
  }
}

 function calc (){

 }
```

Comment: Oh God, a `span` has no type, it's just a span ?

Comment: You are gonna find a lot of bad coding, im just starting out, it still worked back then even with that, I dont think thats the problem

Comment: nope, it's not the problem, just pointed it out, the problem is a typo in this line `for (var i = 0, i < 4; i++) {` the comma should be a semicolon.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! Its all good, im learning better coding habits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop.

Rewrite it as:

```
function oper(operator) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(operators[i] == operator)
      StringOper = operator;
  }
}
```

and it should work.

The problem was that you used a **comma** instead of a **semicolon** in your for statement between the **initialization** and the **condition**.

Check the [MDN document on for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax) for more info.

Comment: What exactly is the bug? Playing the "spot the difference" game is not very helpful.

Comment: this line `for (var i= 0,i<4;i++)` should've been `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` (semicolon instead of a comma)